# Stringio 3.0.6 does not execute properly with arm64 on M1 MacOS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, apple-m1, stringio

I'm trying to install stringio 3.0.6 as a part of project dependencies tree via bundle install, but apparently it does not work as it should because of the error `mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')`.

The full stacktrace is below:

```
<internal:/Users/sviat/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2/lib/ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in 
`require': 
dlopen(/Users/sviat/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/stringio-3.0.6/lib/stringio.bundle, 0x0009):
 tried: '/Users/sviat/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/stringio-3.0.6/lib/stringio.bundle' 
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), 
'/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/sviat/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/stringio-3.0.6/lib/stringio.bundle' (no such file), '/Users/sviat/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/stringio-3.0.6/lib/stringio.bundle' 
(mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')) - 
/Users/sviat/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/stringio-3.0.6/lib/stringio.bundle (LoadError)
```

I'm constantly getting the error above despite I have done everything below:

1. Set `bundle config set force_ruby_platform true`;
2. Installed Ruby with ruby -v prints `ruby 3.1.2p20 (2022-04-12 revision 4491bb740a) [arm64-darwin22]`;
3. Using ZSH with proper config in it and `source ~/.zshrc`.
4. Using ARM terminal with uname -m says `arm64`.
5. I can install stingio with `gem list stringio`, but not with `arch -arm64 gem install stringio`. The error will be as above.
6. Rozetta is not turned on in Terminal setting.

What else I can try? I've reinstalled my ruby and tried to do the same with RBENV, etc. Restarted my laptop and switched the electricity without any success.

MacOS - Ventura 13.4;
Chip - M1.
Ruby - 3.1.2.
RVM - latest.
Terminal - arm64.

Comment: Did you port your machine over from x86_64? If so, you'll need to scrub and reinstall Ruby through `rbenv`.

Comment: Nope, I have a clean mac. Installed via arm64. Removed and installed everything again, still same error

Comment: Do other versions of `stringio` work? It could be a bad build with the wrong binary baked in.

Comment: Tried various versions. Same issue... I believe this is something wrong on my end, I just could not figure out what exactly...

Comment: Worth checking your `gem env`. For what it's worth, `gem install stringio -v 3.0.6` had no issues on my machine, macOS 13.3.1, M1, Ruby 3.2.2.

Comment: Funny, I don't receive this error while running on top of `sudo`... why?

Comment: `sudo` may not be using the same `rbenv` settings and could've used the system Ruby.

Comment: You might be right! I think it's better not to use `sudo` as it leads to other portions of errors. Still, the original issue does not go away.

Comment: Does `gem env` provide any insight? There are situations where, for whatever reason, `gem` is not the one associated with your current Ruby, it's pointing to some relic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253903/discussion-between-sviat-kuzhelev-and-tadman).

Comment: In your stacktrace output there's a reference to `/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Users/...` - seems really odd to be referencing the Preboot volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well by the end of the day I have fixed this up by using rvm instead of rbnev. removed all the stuff related to ruby and rbnev from my machine, reloaded PC, and installed everything on top of rvm

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with rbenv so I remove it.
Restarted my system.
I update/upgrade brew.
And I give it a try with chruby to install it.
It worked!
Probably as the previous comment (trying with rvm), the fresh start was the key.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35478768)